# azure api deployed in multiple region issue

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

In a multi region azure api management setup there is two different subscription keys for same api. What is the best practice client must use to pass api subscription keys so that api call works properly even if request is processed by any of the apim instance in multiregion setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is response from microsoft

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/34340350-subscription-key-client-should-pass-for-api-deploy